# Why does my control function do the opposite of what it's supposed to do?

Tags: c++, function, struct

```
int control(int n, data a[], string cod){

for(int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++){
    if(cod == a[i].code)
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Hello, everyone! this is my control function. it's used to check if a code that has been input by a user already exists in the struct. This is what happens in the "input" function:

```
void input(int &n, data a[]){
string code;

do{
    cout<<"\nInput the code: ";
    cin>> code;
    if((control(n,a,code))>0)
        a[n].code=code;
    else 
        cout<<"\nThe code you've input already exists. Please try again.";
}while((control(n,a,code)) == -1);

n++;
}
```

There are two problems:

1. everytime i input a code it tells me that it already exists, even though it's my first time.
2. it doesn't make me try again, even though the code already exists.

Comment: what does `control` return when it finds the element at the first position? What does the condition `(control(n,a,code))>0` check?

Comment: "_Why does my control function do the opposite of what it's supposed to do?_" Typically, the reason is: `if` condition is written backwards. Just like it is in this case.

Comment: It's (sort of) unrelated to the question at hand, but it tends to be a lot easier to keep track of what your code is doing if you indent it properly.

Comment: btw I am not sure if I understand the code, but I would expect that you can insert one element and only after that you get the error message. Including example input and output would help to clarify

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you call that function `control()`?

Comment: Perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.  Using a debugger is orders of magnitude faster than debugging through StackOverflow!  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by indenting your code so we can more easily understand what it does:

```cpp
int control(int n, data a[], string cod) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (cod == a[i].code)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Ah, so it scans through an array, and returns a value greater than or equal to 0 if a string is present, or -1 if it's absent. Then let's consider the code that uses it:

```cpp
void input(int &n, data a[])
{
    string code;

    do
    {
        cout << "\nInput the code: ";
        cin >> code;
        if ((control(n, a, code)) > 0)
            a[n].code = code;
        else
            cout << "\nThe code you've input already exists. Please try again.";
    } while ((control(n, a, code)) == -1);

    n++;
}
```

So this accepts the code if the return value was greater than 0, and otherwise rejects the code as already existing. This is mostly backwards, but not exactly even that.

My suggestion would be to start by defining an enumeration to give meaningful names to the values you're returning. This makes it much easier to keep track of what's going on:

```cpp
enum { DUPLICATE, UNIQUE };

int control(int n, data a[], string cod) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (cod == a[i].code)
            return DUPLICATE;
    }
    return UNIQUE;
}
```

Now it's much easier to get our condition correct, and much more obvious if we react to it incorrectly:

```cpp
if (control(n, a, code) == UNIQUE)
    a[n].code = code;
else
    cout << "\nThe code is a duplicate";
```

Or, if you prefer to reverse the condition, it's still easy to get correct:

```cpp
if (control(n, a, code) == DUPLICATE)
    cout << "\nThe code is a duplicate";
else
    a[n].code = code;
```

But in particular, if you accidentally get things backwards, it'll be pretty obvious:

```
if (contro(n, a, code) == UNIQUE)
   cout << "\nThe code is a duplicate";
```

At least to me, the contrast between "UNIQUE" on one line, and "duplicate" immediately below it seems fairly obvious.

#### Other Points to Consider

1. I'd advise against having:

   ```cpp
   using namespace std;
   ```

   ...in your code, as you apparently do right now. This is a bad habit that saves a little typing now, but can lead to considerable grief in the long term.
2. I'd also look up `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`, which can already do (more efficiently) what you're using your `data` array to do.
3. If/when you do need something array-like in C++, you probably want to use an `std::array` or `std::vector` rather than the built-in array type. They're much more convenient and help prevent quite a few errors.
4. I'd try to come up with a better name than `control` for a function that tries to show whether a code is already in use. `control` is such a generic name, it's almost impossible to guess what it's supposed to accomplish without looking at its content. A good name for a function does a great deal to clarify the code that uses it, and show what you intend that piece of code to accomplish:

   ```cpp
   std::cin >> new_code;
   if (isDuplicate(new_code))
       std::cerr << "The code you entered is a duplicate. Please try again\n";
   else
       codes.add(new_code);
   ```

Comment: very unlikely, but OP could also have `using std::string; using std::cout;` etc. ;)

Comment: wow, this was very useful! i'm doing c++ in highschool so unfortunately we're pretty much obliged to use `using namespace std`. thank you so much for the `enum` tip (and all of your other tips of course), i really appreciate it and will start using it in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
   cout<<"\nInput the code: ";
   cin>> code;
   if((control(n,a,code))>0)
       a[n].code=code;
   else cout<<"\nThe code you've input already exists. Please try again.";
}while((control(n,a,code))==-1);
```

I see at least two problems here:

- `control` returns `0` when the element is found at the first position, you check for `>0` in the condition
- if the loop body sucessfully inserts the element then `while((control(n,a,code))==-1);` results in an endless loop.

I suggest you to use `std::find_if` to check if an element is already present. With a `std::vector` thats:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct data {
    std::string code;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<data> v;
    std::string foo = "test";
    auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[foo](auto x){ return x.code == foo;});
    bool found = (it == v.end());
}
```

Also consider to use a `std::set` if you want a container with unique entries.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much! fixed it, now it works!

Comment: @neavys Consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.